# main.dart.js not produced on build

Tags: dart, dart2js

I haven't build in a long time so I dont know if this is new or not, but recently I decided to use `async` and `await` to make code look nicer. However, I tried to build just to verity it worked on JS but I am getting two cases depending on what I include in my `pubspec.yaml`:

1. It builds but it doesn't produce `main.dart.js` file in particular.
2. It throws an error blaming `redstone_mapper`

With this `pubspec.yaml` I am getting the first case

```
name: aristadart
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  angular: 1.0.0
  browser: any
  di: any
  fp: any
  http: any
  mongo_dart: any
  redstone: any
  redstone_mapper: any
  redstone_mapper_mongo: any
  shelf_static: any
  async_await:
    git: https://github.com/dart-lang/async_await.git

transformers:
- async_await
- redstone_mapper
- angular:
    html_files:
    - lib/components/login/login.html
    - lib/components/login/nuevo_usuario.html
    - lib/components/home/home.html
    - lib/components/evento/evento.html
    - lib/components/vista/vista.html

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^0.22.4
  barback: ^0.15.2+2
  code_transformers: ^0.2.3+2
  di: ^3.3.3
  route_hierarchical: ^0.6.1
```

Here is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Arista Client</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/arista.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#e6e4e3">
    <nav style= "background-color:#517dbe" class="tab-bar">
        <div class="left-small">
            <a class="item menu-icon">
                <span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
      <div class="middle tab-bar-section">!Bienvenidos a ARISTA Client </div>
      <div  class = "right tab-bar-section">
        <a  href="#" ng-click="logout()"
               class="button radius right tiny"
               ng-if="LoggedIn">
                    Logout
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <br>


    <div class="large-8 small-centered columns" style="background-color:white" class="sombra">
        <br>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>



      <a data-options="align:left" data-dropdown="dropInfo" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="true"></a>
        <ul id="dropInfo" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1">
          <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
        </ul>


    <script src="/js/vendor/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML of your entry page (`index. html`) and the error message of case 2.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is the `index` relevant during build? See update.

Comment: I could't find anything wrong with your `pubspec.yaml` and the script tags in your entry page were my next suspects. You don't get any error messages in the 1st case?

Comment: For some other unknown reason, if I serve the application with `pub`, I get a `not found` error on `main.dart`!!!

Comment: Can you post full error message? Any stack trace?